# How to join 3 table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I wanna to join 3 table in 1 page and display it...

> ```
>    $id = $_REQUEST["Emp_ID"];
>    $test = mysql_query("select * from Employee left join department on employee.dept_id = department.dept_id 
>                                                left join leave on employee.leave_id = leave_id where Emp_ID = $id");
>    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($test);
> ```

Comment: got error :mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: Try printing the result of `mysql_error()` before calling `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trying to join `Employee` by using the name `employee`. if that is what you intend you first need to create an alias.

```
 select * from Employee AS employee 
 left join department on employee.dept_id = department.dept_id 
 left join leave on employee.leave_id = leave.leave_id 
 where employee.Emp_ID = $id
```

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning SQL Injection and parameterisation...

Answer (score -1):

Should really consult google before coming here.

```
SELECT t1.col, 
       t1.col,
       t2.col,
       t2.col,
       t3.col,
       t3.col
FROM    t1
    INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.foreignkey = t1.primarykey
    LEFT JOIN t3 on t3.foreignkey = t1.primarykey
```

If you can't follow that.. Google.